# How can I know the value of a variable in bison while debugging with GDB?

Tags: c++, gdb, bison, bisonc++

I'm trying to write a small compiler which can parse some commands I type.

The command I try to parse is:

```
create class something = create class do_something ;
```

My code would be something like this:

```
grammar : my_grammar
        {
            list<Class1 *> *obj = new list<Class1 *>;
            obj->push_back($1);
        }

my_grammar : my_definition SEMICOLON
           {
               report("something detected!");
               $$ = $1;
            }

my_definition : CREATE CLASS class_name EQU class_expression
               {
                   $5->setClassName(*$3);
                   $$ = $5;
                }

class_expression : CREATE CLASS operand_name
                 {
                     $$ = new OperandClass();
                     $$->setOperationType("createClass");
                     $$->setOperandName(*$3);
                  }
```

However, when I try to call the parser somewhere else, I can't get the `Class` I have defined before.

I guess there must be something wrong with the parser and have done some debugging with GDB. But I just can't step in the function `push_back()`, neither can I print the information of `obj` correctly.

So, I am wondering if there is a way that I can get the value of `$$` or `$1` while using GDB.  Simply type in `p $$` would print something else.

Comment: Look at the spaghetti code that bison spews out. It shouldn't be hard to figure out which variables/structures represent the $$ and $1 placeholders. bison turns the grammar into robo-generated C++, replacing all of the yacc-y stuff with C++ containers and objects. Once you figure out what they are, you'd print their contents just like any other objects'.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I just have a look about the spaghetti code, and find the corresponding line of `obj->push_back($1)` in it while `$1` is  replaced with `(((yyGLRStackItem const *)yyvsp)[YYFILL ((1) - (1))].yystate.yysemantics.yysval.OperandClass)`. However, when I set a breakpoint in generated `cpp` file and try to print the value, the program would always jump back to `ypp` file I wrote and says "No symbol YYFILL in current context". Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: That's because YYFILL is, most likely, a macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is probably declaring a variable of the same type as your rule (`$$` has this type) and assigning it.

```
%union {
  int I;
}
%type<I> rule whatever

rule: whatever {
    int foo = $1;
    // printf("%d", foo);
    $$ = $1;
}
```

You can then either see it in the debugger or just printf it.

The debugger cannot go inside `push_back` or other standard functions unless you have standard library debugging information installed.

As for your question in general, your `obj` is local to the rule, which gets transformed to the function by Bison, and is not visible outside it unless you store it somewhere else, e.g. in a global.

Comment: @forumulator's answer is much better.  It's easy to remember: for `$$` use `yyval.<type>`.  For `$<number>` use `yyvsp[<number> - 1].<type>`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using bison with the C templates, bison has a variable `yyval` and an array `yyvsp`, both of type `YYSTYPE`, which we define using the `%union` option in the bison `parser.y` file. The `$$` of a rule is given by the union member of `yyval`, and the symbols in the production are members in the array `yyvsp`. For example, for the union:

```
%union {
  int t1;
  float t2;
}

%type <t1> nt1;
%type <t2> nt2;
%%
input : nt1 | nt2;
nt1 : CONSTANT { $$ = $1; } ;
nt2 : FCONSTANT { $$ = $1 };
%%
int main() { yyparse(); }
```

while using gdb:

1. You can refer to the left hand of a production, for example `nt1` by it's type, i.e `$$` for `nt1` can be referred to by `yyval.t1`
2. `$i` on the R.H.S can be referred to by: `yyvsp[i - t].type` where i is the index of the symbol to be referenced, and t is the total number of symbols(terminal and non-terminals) in production.

So, for example, `$1` in both rules can be referred to by `yyvsp[1-1].t1` and `yyvsp.[0].t2`, respectively.

Comment: OP should select this answer.